# Is it fine to call users "nerds" in comments?

Tags: support, comment-flags

I recently flagged a comment on a LQ question, posted by the OP in response to other comments letting them know what's wrong with their question. This was his comment:

> I need an expert advise and that's it. I know that **nerds** will flag this question as too broad or opinion based.

**Here is a screenshot:**
[image: screenshot]

I flagged it as rude/offensive but it was declined, and yes - I don't specifically mind being called a "nerd", but perhaps other users could get offended, or it might have the potential to start a small comments war.

Note that the comment is now gone, and I'm confused - Did the OP delete it? because a moderator declined this flag. Is this type of comments is accepted - I need to understand what to do in future if I see a minor insults in the comments.

Comment: Hmm, seems strange. Maybe it's to do with the fact that the entire question was a dumpster fire easy to tell from a mile away? But that might warrant  *ignoring*, not explicit rejection

Comment: He didn't even used that nerd for descriping nerdy/geeky people, instead he mean pedantic/"rule loving" people who don't appreciate his off-topic question where OP spent so little time into it. So of course this is rude.

Comment: Douchebro asks terrible question, nerds shut it down. All is right in the world.

Comment: Possibly a miss-click. I flagged a chain of comments before; 7 of them where declined and the rest helpful and yet all were removed.

Comment: I would never downvote such a question since I would be ignoring everything after 'I'm a beginner PHP developer' and moving on, but now I've read it here, it's a hopelessly bad question and an insulting/disrepectful comment. Unfortunately, all too common.

Comment: @Alon I'm guessing this was a mis-click. The mod that declined the flag swiftly went back and deleted it anyway. I can't speak for them, so I'm not going to - I've let them know about this post.

Comment: @Pekka웃 _"Douchebro"_ That was new and refreshing for me. A decent nerd had a big grin. THX for that.

Comment: @JonClements If that's what you're guessing then it's good enough for me. I accepted the answer I liked the most and learned that the comment is indeed rude, and i'll flag similar comments in future if they ever come around

Comment: @torazaburo I sense sarcasm in your comment, i'll flag it for a moderator :p

Comment: @JonClements is exactly right, I messed up. There were several flagged comments on that post, I'd intended to leave some and delete some, but I accidentally declined all the flags. Once I realised this I did come back and delete "nerd" comment before Jon pointed this meta question out.

Comment: I think most people probably don't find "nerds" that offensive. On the other hand, I think a comment where the OP admits that they know they're asking a too broad/opinion-based question may actually add some value in terms of getting the question deleted a little faster.

Comment: Look at all these nerds discussing the use of "nerds"

Comment: @Flexo: I'd guess that's an answer to this q?

Comment: I find the word "nerd" itself slightly offensive, but I've got my big-boy pants on today, and I can take it.  I'm rather more offended by the commenter's apparent intent to deprecate people who behave in a way he doesn't like.  *That* is not a characteristic of polite discourse.  I'd probably not bother to flag it myself, but it having been flagged, yes, that flag should be accepted.

Comment: I'm assuming upvotes to this question are approving the OP's action of flagging the comment, rather than as a response of "yes" to the title.

Comment: [Obligatory](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7a_sx3ozoXI)

Comment: It's extremely funny how "I need an expert's advice" almost all the time actually means "I'm so full of myself that anyone knowing more must be an expert"

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I would have flagged the comment as well. It's obvious that OP wasn't saying "nerd" in a positive manner, the comment seems offensive and I expect it to be deleted regardless of the entire question that it was part of.

Maybe the moderator didn't pay much attention when he reviewed the comment, and this happens. Otherwise, I would really want to know why it was declined.

Comment: That's what I think but wasn't sure. Of course it's OK if this is the case. I don't mind having declined flag if a moderator made a mistake, I just wanted to know if the community agree that this type of comments are unacceptable

Comment: Just for completeness' sake: [here is the mod's verification](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349566/is-it-fine-to-call-users-nerds-in-comments?cb=1#comment475536_349566) that declining the flag was simply a mistake.

Comment: Yeah, the comment was rude regardless of whether it contained the word 'nerd.'

Comment: ^ This. Context counts, and name-calling violates "be nice".  "Nerd" isn't *inherently* an insult; I often use it to describe myself.  But in this context, it's clearly intended as one: "here's the name I'm assigning to anyone who does something I've made clear I dislike."  And name-calling doesn't fly here. It's fine to say why you find a given behavior undesirable, but it's not okay to say that anyone who does that behavior is a [something].

Comment: Brief summary:  https://media.giphy.com/media/A9KfKenpqNDfa/giphy.gif

Answer (score 17):

**The way this comment was phrased violates the [Be Nice policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)**.

It isn't really the word so much as how it was used. Although, to be fair, this is [google's definition of the word nerd](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+nerd), and it isn't exactly flattering:

> a foolish or contemptible person who lacks social skills or is boringly studious

While the word "nerd" itself may or may not be of interest, the intent is really the issue. Many polite, inclusive, and friendly posts, events and phrases include the word nerd. There are also several alternative definitions of nerd which are more aimed at the technical expert angle; culturally, it seems that lately there has been more of a movement to "own" the word, so to speak.

The problem with the comment was its tone. It was an attempt to belittle, to place a negative connotation on a group of "others" in order to influence a decision. While there may be definitions or uses of the word nerd that are flattering or inclusive, the usage here was in the form of name-calling to alienate a group of people.

All said and done though, it was clear this comment was out of line. Moderators have a tough job, and sometimes in their constant struggle against the firehose they make small mistakes. This was one of them, it was corrected, and I don't think there should be a witch hunt for this word because of one accidental misuse of the moderation feature.

Answer (score 14):

It is abuse. A self-identifying trap.

Vis. "I am saying that if you criticise this then you are not a nice person - now I dare you to criticise and so show that you are not a nice person".

The word 'nerd' is pretty irrelevant, any 'possibly' negative term would have done.

Answer (score -11):

I'd agree with it being deleted/edited as "noise", but if we followed the "people might be offended by it" methodology it would be a pretty boring place.

Answer (score -13):

Whether is fine or not, *it depends for each person*.

Just two examples:

- At school, I met a kid who has answer for any subject. All *(except me)* call him *nerdo* (nerd). He didn't correct us.
- Calling me nerd is fairly wrong. I'm not one.

**tl; dr:** Flag as unconstructive and move on: this is what I do when replies from SO users doesn't add value to the question or answer.

Comment: I think the context here matters more than how someone would respond to the word in general. The person leaving the comment was complaining about the people who would eventually close their off-topic question. Even someone who's normally OK with the word would understand it to be an insult in that case.

Comment: "*Calling me nerd is fairly wrong. I'm not one.*" - denial. Join us.

Answer (score -41):

The term "nerd" is tricky, as some people self-identify as "nerd", whereas other dislike the term and consider it somewhat pejorative. There's no real "standard meaning".

So context is everything. And in this context I wouldn't consider "nerd" to be particularly rude or offensive. It's probably not intended to be flattering here, and it's a completely useless comment for sure. But offensive? Probably not.

A context where "nerd" would be offensive would be something like "Stack Overflow meta nerds with no life and nothing better to do than to close questions!", which is a real example I encountered a while ago.

---

Personally, I would have just ignored that comment. The question is terrible and cannot possibly be salvaged. There's no need to "clean" the comments on questions such as this, and the best ending for them is quick closure and deletion.

Comment: But that's pretty much exactly the context he's using it in here, isn't it?

Comment: @Pekka웃 The problem is that you don't know which meaning of "nerd" the author intended here. Not for sure, anyway. Whereas you *do* when you tack on something like a nerd-stereotype like "no life". Personally, I'd err on the side of caution before flagging something like this "rude/offensive".

Comment: "I know that {pejorative} will {do something I don't like}" -- this seems to be the only possible structure here, contextually. There is no room for "nerds" (or anything else) to be *positive*, certainly, and precious little even for it to be neutral. At best you could have something like "I know that some people will vote to close this question", but this is *still* slightly pejorative.

Comment: NO, it IS insulting and disrespectful.  There is zero doubt.  If I was to behave in a similar manner to question-posters, I'm sure it would be flagged and I would get suspended.  'I need expert advise and that's it' - 'you nerds are not experts and should not comment.  The experts I want are those I can get to answer my off-topic questions for free, everyone else take a hike'.

Comment: The thing is that "nerds" isn't necessarily seen as a pejorative @NathanTuggy. You could swap "nerd" out with "people" here without problem. Obviously this won't make "people" a pejorative.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: The point I was making is that *even if you do* swap "[some] people" in, *the structure is still pejorative*, and forces a negative connotation of the word to be chosen if any exists, or a negative shading to be created. Since nerd does have some fairly significant possible negative connotations, bang, those have to be used. The two halves of the sentence aren't going to have different tones.

Comment: Frankly, I don't see that at all in this comment @NathanTuggy. It's a 100% useless comment from a frustrated user, and it's probably even *disrespectful*, but "rude or offensive"? I really can't see that here. I think your "you nerds are not experts"-meaning that you give it really is a stretch.

Comment: I don't see that there's any difference between being "disrespectful" and being "rude or offensive".  I will agree that the word "offensive" is maybe a little strong for the context.  Nonetheless, if something disrespects someone, they would be perfectly justified in being offended by it.

Comment: Big +1 for @Carpetsmoker, since you do not see what's not written or that which is not written, which doesn't seem to be the case for the majority of people involved in this thread. Hats off to you sir. Rudeness is merely implied, by the reader, in this case, but looking objectively, nothing's rude here. It's evident that the user is fussing because noone is going to solve his problem today.