# Moderator repeatedly deleting and undeleting their own answers

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, meta, deleted-answers, moderators

Just something I noticed, lately:

There's a moderator that (imo, too often) deletes and then undeletes their own answers on Meta. Often, this mostly happens without any edits made while the answer is deleted.

I don't know what the reasoning behind it is, but it looks somewhat unsavory. It seems like an emotional action instead of a rational one.
(or maybe I'm just completely misinterpreting what's going on)

It *comes across as if* the moderator is trying to hide something, or just can't make up their mind.
<sup>(I'm not saying that's the case, just that that's how it looks to me)</sup>

Sure, that can happen once, but it's starting to look like a pattern (Multiple different answers / questions)

My suggestion:

- If you're not sure of your actions, don't write an answer (yet).
  Discuss it with your colleague moderators, first.
- If your answer is met with negativity, don't delete it. Own up to it, learn from
  it.

And if these are steps you're already taking, that's awesome! Then it just means I completely mis-interpreted what was going on.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately the actions here stand out to me because I have also seen this -- negative votes? Delete. It's a pattern that worries me, for reasons I won't get into on this thread.

Comment: I'm not sure how this sort of behavior is acceptable from a moderator. The undelete is supposed to be strictly for correcting deleted actions. Not to be used whimsically with delete to protect your own answer from downvotes or whatever at the time logic results in the deletion.

Comment: Hmya, I think most of us had a rough idea that it was going to take a while to get this moderator up to speed.  If we give, erm, it a chance that it will surely happen.

Comment: I am not sure if this is a fair representation of what happened. The answer was brought up in another discussion after the deletion. Another mod stepped in etc.

Comment: I think it would be best to avoid specifying which moderator was in question here. This seems to be more about conduct, not a callout.

Comment: @user2285236: This is not about that one answer. This is becoming a pattern. A pattern I'd rather not see from any moderator. This discussion is a chance to reflect on that.

Comment: eh, i think this is jumping the gun quite a bit.

Comment: @Cerbrus: I'm not sure why this is wrong. It certainly isn't *useful* in any way I understand. It accomplishes very little, but I don't see how it's wrong or something users or moderators shouldn't do.

Comment: Ooooh, oooooh, was it me? Please, tell me it's me! Did I guess it right? *bounce*.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: I wouldn't say it's wrong, it's just... really unusual behavior. A normal user doing this would've received a message from us asking if they're... ok.

Comment: @BoltClock Let's be honest, someone else doing that woulda been put in time out until a discussion was had about the behavior since it's not constructive and could be seen as abusing the vote system.

Comment: (I feel oddly tempted to delete my comment now, then undelete it, then delete it again, ...)

Comment: @BoltClock: Thanks. That's why I posted this. It's unusual, and sends a weird message.

Comment: @Trasiva: We would not suspend someone for that behaviour unless there was a history of moderator contact already.

Comment: @Trasiva: We'd put them on timeout if they were actively mashing delete/undelete at the time...

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't mean a full account suspension, more like a revocation of privs. Assuming that's possible, if not...maybe that should be. Or like Bolt said, timeout. Same desired effect.

Comment: @Trasiva: Yeah that's not possible. There are only a handful of non-critical privs we can limit, but not the core posting/voting/editing/commenting privs. Those have to be suspended and unsuspended collectively.

Comment: @Trasiva: I'm not sure why a user would be sanctioned for behavior that isn't actively harmful to the site. Yes, it's decidedly odd behavior, but it isn't incorrect behavior.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: Want some help with that?

Comment: You could lock a specific post to prevent deletion while talking with them. Content dispute lock. @BoltClock :)

Comment: @Catija: Oh... yeah... how'd I forget that.

Comment: @BoltClock *A normal user doing this* ... so we just have to accept moderators are not normal? I didn't see that one coming ... ;)

Comment: I've noticed this as well.  Not entirely sure why it's occurring.  We may be missing context into the matter.  It seems very odd especially if it's on Meta.

Comment: Now, the next natural question is, "does this matter"?  I'm tempted to think "it does" since a moderator has the power to open and reopen any question with impunity, whereas we mere mortals do not.  I'm open to receive guidance, though.

Comment: @Catija I think mods can still delete and undelete posts when they're locked. So it is not useful to lock the post in this case.

Comment: @Bhargav Rao: Catija and I were talking about regular users. Neither locking nor suspending would deter a diamond user in this case.

Comment: On a similar, IMO even slightly more serious note, I've also noticed some mod's poorly received posts getting disassociated. I don't think bailing out of negatively received Meta posts is a good use of that mechanic, especially when the author is a moderator.

Comment: @Baum mit Augen: Well, given that post disassociation is performed on a case-by-case basis, at least there's a decent chance the staff gave it some careful consideration before following through with it.

Comment: @BoltClock I'm sure they did; I just wanted to express that this should happen *very* rarely, if at all, and should not even come close to become a normal or standard procedure, when talking about moderators' Meta posts.

Comment: @Baum mit Augen: Agreed. Case-by-case basis.

Comment: What exactly is there to discuss here?

Comment: I think such things could be cleaned out from the database by a regular maintenance task.

Comment: While I think I agree with the premise of this question -- you shouldn't regularly delete/undelete your content, especially if you are not making changes to it -- this doesn't appear to be *asking* anything, or invoking any kind of discussion.

Comment: @peterh What exactly do you mean? The system should remove these "delete/undelete" events? Isn't it a good idea to keep a history of these things? Mods can't see it all, all the time. Regular users can catch these situations and then call it out as needed, no?

Comment: @Patrice I think if there is a quick delete/undelete loop, then the intermediate events could be removed from the post history. A similar feature is already in the software: quickly consecutive edits from the same person are merged, too. As far I know, also a quick consecutive upvote/unupvote chain is merged into a single event.

Comment: @Patrice As a test, I voted up and unupvoted your [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27830300/1783163) answer 5 times. Do you see anything in your rep history? No. Some similar could be done also with the delete/undelete events, in my opinion.

Comment: @peterh there is a difference. vote/unupvote isn't abusive, it makes sence to remove it (imho). Deletion/undeletion I feel could be more problematic, so removing visibility can stop other users from realizing there is a problem. (thx for the edit, btw, I do have trailing periods I keep on forgetting)

Comment: @peterh and if it's a quick delete/undelete, I would tend to agree (not 100% sure, but I still think it makes sense). Something like 2-3 minutes. However I see at least a 25 minutes difference between the last two events, so I think this is worth not removing.

Comment: @Patrice Also edits can be abusive, but also they are merged. I don't know the exact rules, but if you edit the same post quickly, only the last edit will be in the post history. I think a good logic could be that the delete/undelete event is merged if and only if 1) it neutralizes exactly the previous posthistory event 2) it happens quickly after that (for example, in 5 minutes or so).

Comment: @peterh I can stand behind that!

Comment: SO meta has more drama than a soap opera

Comment: @peterh - "voted up and unupvoted 5 times"... the reason nothing showed as a result of that in rep history was caching. If you were to cycle it slower, it would show up temporarily. However, that doesn't mean the database didn't record your action.

Comment: It makes perfect sense to delete or undeleting your own answers, modererator or not. Why would you notice this or care if someone decides to remove their own answer?

Comment: I find it alarming that this inflammatory post is now trending.

Comment: The post in question seems to have disappeared again.

Comment: Pointing out egregious abuse of the site mechanics while censoring out anything that could be used to identify the abuser has to be the most gracious and tactful way to handle the situation I can imagine. What about this do you think is inflammatory? The fact that it's trending does not reflect on the post, it reflects on the behavior the post is addressing.

Comment: The reality of the situation as outlined by Tim Post does not change my opinion, which is that given the information available at the time, *this* post is fine. If you, @coldspeed, meant the post in question and not the one we're commenting on, I apologize.

Comment: @JohnP Not the post in question, because there was nothing inflammatory about that. I meant _this_ one, but given the fact that we have reached an amicable conclusion, I don't so much care anymore.

Comment: @JohnP - Where is this " egregious abuse" you seem to be referencing?

Comment: Hyde deletes; Jekkyl undeletes.

Comment: @TravisJ Like I said, Tim Post explained what appeared as abuse at the time of the original question. To answer more directly: nowhere, or at least not where we were looking.

Comment: @TravisJ The abuse I was referring to was any of several interpretations prior to the real explanation - including resetting reputation while editing to avoid personal responsibility instead of using 'undelete' to correct an accidental deletion - however the point here is only that abuse was apparent when the example was scrubbed of identifiable content, and it was scrubbed to protect the presumed innocent, all of which seems like appropriate conduct to me. If this were intended as inflammatory, I would not expect any redaction. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @JohnP - That is an extremely generous amount being given to the benefit of the doubt. We all know that inflammatory content isn't allowed. So, what is allowed is a gray line, which some have a skill for walking on.

Comment: @TravisJ Is that to say that (if the content were inflammatory) we were supposed to infer the subject of the post? Or that we were supposed to get worked up about the idea of a moderator behaving this way despite no one in particular to get mad at? I think I'm giving less to the benefit of the doubt and taking more with Occam's Razor. If we should give the benefit of the doubt to people who engage in the deletion/undeletion behavior, why attribute malevolence to anyone questioning the behavior who hasn't gotten that advice? For the record I've never moderated; I'm asking in earnest.

Comment: @YvetteColomb: No, it's based on  more than one question, but as I explained a ___bazillion times___ already, I had no ill intentions with the question, so please stop telling people I had ill intentions. I don't have a problem with you as a person, but with ___some of your actions___. If you make mistakes, I am going to call you out on it. That's not some petty personal vendetta. It's ___credibility___.

Comment: @Cerbrus The point multiple people here are making is that, your intentions aside, the hypothetical explanations for the behaviour surrounding the core of this question make it come across as not just a call-out, but as an attempt to actively undermine that credibility.

Comment: @duplode: that people interpret it that way is pretty clear. But they need to understand that that was not the way I intended the question to be interpreted, as I’ve said time and time again.

Comment: I think what @Cerbrus is saying is that, just because people have taken this particular meaning from his post, it doesn't mean that that actually is what *they* meant, and at the end of the day, the original intent of the OP is what matters, not the peoples' interpretation on what was intended by Cerbrus. He did also clarify what he meant in his edit: '*And if these are steps you're already taking, that's awesome! Then it just means I completely mis-interpreted what was going on.*' - He acknowledged the implications of this post and addressed it respectfully.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I've done it too. I can't find the specific examples, but I can give the timeline of how it happened:

- Robert Harvey and I were basically the only two mods making decisions to close down overly-subjective questions, this wasn't making us popular (fun fact, he and I developed what later became the 'historical lock' by editing that phrasing into the post).
- Someone came to meta in a really bad mood taking issue with something I'd done. I don't think it was even related to closing, I think it was deleting a non-answer.
- I mustered every ounce of word smithing I could muster in order to berate and humiliate the person in full view, without *technically* violating any policy. I was really pissed, tired, and sad.

... the post started getting ***up-voted*** like crazy. My better senses kicked in, and I deleted it. What I wrote wasn't something that should be coming from an emissary of the site.

It went through a few different cycles. I changed the wording, but that didn't fix the comments under it that were now totally out of context, and now I had this post that had lots of upvotes that was *totally* different than what folks had voted on previously, and I just deleted it.

I'm pretty sure I emailed Jeff or (at the time) possibly Sam (Waffles) or Rebecca, I don't think Shog yet worked here. I never followed up on it. My guess is, they just disassociated it for me and moved on.

But in any event, I think evidence of someone trying to just *fix* a mistake can sometimes look an awful lot like someone trying to hide one, but there's no real hiding on this kind of platform. Try and give folks, especially those that do a *lot* of emotionally-intense work, the benefit of the doubt.

In this particular case? I think it's pretty benign.

Comment: Thanks for your input, Tim. Considering the other answers I’ve gotten, I agree that there wasn’t anything wrong in this case :-)

Comment: It should probably be noted that in your case, you made changes to your post between deletion and undeletion. At least in the screenshot above, there appears to be no change made to the post. It's just a confusing delete - undelete cycle.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Well, it's confusing to me looking at it after the fact (because you don't get context in that situation), so, yes it *is* confusing, and, even after knowing more context, it's still confusing to me why it was deleted and undeleted with no changes. In my opinion you should leave something deleted unless you are going to make changes to it. If it's really that important to some discussion that you need to undelete it, okay, whatever. But then *leave it* undeleted. The unnecessarily confusing part is the *repetition* of the act, especially in such short order.

Comment: This is such a human answer. Love it. How often do people publicly admit to mistakes with such grace?

Comment: @YvetteColomb Shog was talking about wrong answers that serve as obstacles. If that applies to your post, delete it, like I said before. If for some reason it needs to be undeleted, then undelete it and leave it undeleted. *Like I said*, the confusing part is the fact that this happened *multiple times*, and that there was no change to the post between deletions. I'm not really that interested in what you do, but other people probably are because you are an elected moderator and so your actions are going to be in the spotlight, especially for those whom your actions directly affect.

Comment: @YvetteColomb: I like your answer on my question, but your comments on several places are becoming increasingly aggressive towards me. I'm interested in what happens on SO/meta. If that happens to involve you, that's not my fault. I'm active on meta around the same time you seem to be, so we __are going to run into each other__. If you, as a mod, do something I find to be un-mod-like, I _am_ going to call you out on it. ___Just as I would any other mod.___ If you write a meta answer I disagree with, ___I am going to comment___, just like I would on any other mod's answer.

Comment: No, @YvetteColomb. We just disagree a lot. This isn’t a personal vendetta. We can disagree as adults.

Comment: All the evidently deleted comments here are ironic

Comment: @Cerbrus Stop answering your own comments. Haha, what a good laugh that was

Comment: There used to be a reply here stating the comments were undeleted, but apparently they're gone again. This is pretty similar to what the question was about. Comments being deleted > undeleted > deleted again. I still think that's weird.

Answer (score 26):

This feels kinda passive-aggressive.

But whatever. Let's hit it head on!

> If you're not sure of your actions, don't write an answer (yet). Discuss it with your colleague moderators, first.

I have my own opinions. My colleagues have their own opinions. Other users have their own opinions. I'd rather hear folks' honest opinions and be free to express my own than be forced to parrot the voice of a committee and pretend that I'm listening.

I'd rather try to convince you that I'm right and fail than know going in that I don't agree with the words I'm writing and secretly hope they fail to persuade.

> If your answer is met with negativity, don't delete it. Own up to it, learn from it.

If I'm wrong, I'm wrong. Sometimes, I don't have all the information; sometimes, I just made the wrong call. Sometimes, I think I'm right for years... And then someone convinces me otherwise. It takes a prohibitive ego to leave a wrong, unhelpful or misleading answer up once you know it is a stumbling block.

**For the record:** over the past decade I've deleted 393 answers across these sites, with an even 256 of those on Stack Overflow, 92 on MSE, and 17 here on MSO, with scores ranging from -16 to 188.

I'll leave you with this screenshot...

[image: 5 delete/undelete cycles]

Comment: You were just testing the delete/undelete functionality, weren't you?

Comment: I honestly have no idea what I was thinking there.

Comment: You don't think it's a cause for concern the same way too many edits on a single post could be someone either iterating on their post (OK) or bumping it (not OK)? Or if it becomes a pattern across multiple posts (which this doesn't appear to be a case of, but still something that could happen)?

Comment: It *could* be, @BoltClock - I mean, the record holders for most delete/undelete cycles on a post are Nicael and Jeremy, so that kinda says... something? OTOH, this is pretty rare and pretty benign.

Comment: For a more convincing argument, you should also include the timestamps of those deletions (the part on the right that you chose to cut out :) )

Comment: I didn't put that screenshot there to convince anyone, @coldspeed. I put it there to brag.

Comment: Well, colour me impressed then!

Comment: TRIVIA: the record for the most self-deletions on a single post, network-wide, *ever*, is 21 held by the two people mentioned in a previous comment. The runner-up is some math person. There are well under a thousand posts with more'n 2 self-deletions in their history network-wide. I'm not overly worried about this as a general pattern.

Comment: Interestingly, the answer that made me decide to post about it has now been deleted again. Sure, it's not necessarily "wrong" or "bad", but I hope you can see it sends a bit of a weird message when one repeatedly deletes and undeletes their own (meta) answer. If the moderator that inspired me to write this sees this, and thinks _"Oh, in the future I'll consider how this action looks to (normal) users"_, I consider it a win. That's all I wanted, to raise awareness that "flip-flopping" like that can be perceived as less harmless than it probably is.

Comment: For future reference, it's totally fine to ask a question here that is essentially, "this looks weird, please explain it?" @Cerbrus. I disagree pretty strongly with your suggestions though, hence this answer.

Comment: @Shog9: At least it makes for a more interesting answer than _"Eyup"_. ;-) Considering the other answers I've gotten, I'm quite satisfied. Just haven't decided what answer to accept, yet.

Answer (score 9):

### It's ok to delete downvoted posts.

[Should I delete my own downvoted answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263046/should-i-delete-my-own-downvoted-answer)

> [Upon receiving a downvote,](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/263048/3956566)
>
> 1. I review my answer and ask myself, "is there something I can improve here"? If there is, and I have time, I improve it.
> 2. If I no longer feel my answer provides anything useful to future readers of the question, I delete it.
> 3. If I still think my answer is useful and accurate, I laugh heartily at the poor deluded sucker who just wasted a downvote, and move on.

I went through the network recently and deleted dozens of downvoted posts, on main and meta sites. I cleaned house. I did not delete questions with answers on them, I did delete some upvoted questions that had no answers, that were closed. I consulted mods, via flags on each site I was tidying up on and some of the mods let me know which were worthwhile keeping around. I did all of this in consultation with [Tim Post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/50049/tim-post). It was [Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9) and some other users who were cleaning up their posts who inspired me to do the same.

I also requested to have two posts disassociated from my account, which was actioned by the Community Managers. So if there's issues with this, then it's something to be asked of the Community Team, as they approved it and I did it with consultation with them.

#### To answer your question.

> There's a moderator that (imo, too often) deletes and then undeletes
>   their own answers on Meta. Often, this mostly happens without any
>   edits made while the answer is deleted.

If I delete and undelete a post, it's usually to give myself space to edit it, as I can see it needs improvement. I am busy in my life  and don't always have the time to address what is needed in an edit immediately.

[This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368079/why-was-my-comment-removed-from-this-question/368087#368087) is the post that was deleted and undeleted numerous without being unedited. And let's be clear it has been deleted a total of 3 times.

It was temporarily undeleted, as it was being discussed elsewhere and this discussion came up twice - so it was undeleted twice.

As you can see in this professional image -> undeleted when being discussed -> deleted 3 times -> last time was after sleeping.

[image]

> I don't know what the reasoning behind it is, but it looks somewhat
>   unsavory. It seems like an emotional action instead of a rational one.

It was temporarily undeleted, as it was being discussed elsewhere. It was a logical decision.

> (or maybe I'm just completely misinterpreting what's going on)

Yes. Yes, you are completely misinterpreting what's going on.

> It comes across as if the moderator is trying to hide something, or
>   just can't make up their mind.

I'm not trying to hide something. I've stated the facts above.  I can make up my mind. FWIW I've bought real estate and lived in it for many years, decided upon academic paths, requiring years of commitment and have held to those. So yes, I can make up my mind. I can make a decision and stick to it.

> Sure, that can happen once, but it's starting to become a pattern
>   (Multiple different answers / questions)

This is not true. It happened once. A pattern, by definition, is something that repeats or recurs.

> My suggestion:
>
> If you're not sure of your actions, don't write an answer (yet).
>   Discuss it with your colleague moderators, first. If your answer is
>   met with negativity, don't delete it. Own up to it, learn from it.

Thank you for your guidance Cerbrus, I took your advice and waited to reply.

I do seek a lot of guidance, from the mod team, [Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9) and [Tim Post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/50049/tim-post).

I own up for every [mistake](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368092/why-was-i-suspended/368097#368097) I make on this site and ever had. I'm [open and honest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293213/why-we-dont-keep-public-records-of-suspensions/293335#293335), but I do make mistakes. I do  work hard to serve the community, which of late has been challenging, due to the [state of flux in the site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/welcoming).

### A better way to ask your question.

This post could easily have been:

Hey Yvette: I've noticed you were un/deleting this post without editing it? Is this a pattern? I'm wondering why you did that?

It's asking for clarification and facts without using slurs. Isn't that nicer than casting accusations that my intentions are disingenuous or I'm emotional and not rational?

*p.s. I will take the advice of [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/368129/3956566) and post a comment when I delete a downvoted post, I believe is not useful, from now on, so >10K users can see why.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. While I don't agree with all of it, this alleviates up most of my concerns.

Comment: Just for the record: I'm not accusing you of being unable to make up your mind. I'm not claiming you don't discuss things. I'm not saying that you don't think. All I am saying is that unexplained actions sometimes can lead one to think a step was skipped. If that's not the case, great! Again, best intentions, here.

Comment: @Cerbrus I addressed every word in your post, as you wrote it. I suggest you take your own advice and `Own up to it, learn from it`.

Comment: Okay, the _"It comes across as"_ part is not an accusation. I'm sorry if it reads like one, that was never my intention.

Comment: I am talking about _A better way to ask your question_ part. That is really good, but do you write this answer as it is if delete/undelete did by non-moderator or low rep user?

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson sorry I'm a little confused by your question.

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson oh yes this answer applies to any user. Mod or not mod. Mods come under more scrutiny due to the special privileges they've been given.

Comment: `Okay, the "It comes across as" part is not an accusation. I'm sorry if it reads like one, that was never my intention.` then maybe you need to take more time to consider what you want to say and how? ;) It totally, unambiguously read like one even with only a very fleeting knowledge of the past weeks' Meta discussions.

Comment: @Pekka웃: Then I hope the line I just added removes some of the ambiguity.

Comment: Personally, to make this question look like a good-faith Meta contribution I would remove the insinuations entirely and replace them with something like "I don't know what the reasoning behind it is, but it looks weird and I'd like it cleared up." and get rid of (or edit) the advice at the bottom because it makes it look like I *actually* am completely sure of what I described as mere possibilities in the paragraph above. By accident, I'm sure. ;) The rest of the question looks fine to me.

Comment: @Pekka웃 and all moderators, OP hide the who is the moderator, he doesn't want to make trouble to Shog. He asked this question because he loves this sites. He want to make more better place this. But  many moderators try to find mistakes of OP's questions, why is that? Because of he find some behavior of another moderator? If this delete/undelete part done by normal user all these moderators won't act like this... `My English is bad, so my words may look like rude`, but I don't want to rude, I just feel that  some moderators replies are not good in this post

Comment: In this particular post I was actually writing a comment when you deleted it. Then you undeleted it and I started writing a comment again, and then you deleted your answer again before I could finish it :-( I appreciate that you're free to delete your own posts as you see fit, but to be honest it is quite annoying on meta. I don't think that using the "delete/edit/undelete" cycle as a matter of habit is good form on meta, it's kind of like shouting "hold all discussion please!" in the middle of a discussion.

Comment: I also don't think that deleting downvoted posts on meta as a matter of habit is a good idea, either. Downvoted posts and their associated discussion are often useful on meta (this is different from the main site). An example might be [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/349568/660921). clearly the community at large disagrees with what I wrote. Keeping the answer adds value to clarify what *exactly* the community considers rude, and deleted it would be a loss. Meta is a conversation, and removing parts of the conversation later on seems unhelpful to me.

Comment: Sure, not a problem @YvetteColomb; pretty sure I've done it myself on a few occasions over the years. It's just that the language of your answer – as well as the phrasing of this question – suggests you *frequently* do this. I don't know if that's actually the case as I don't visit meta that often these days, but I just wanted to say that doing it *frequently* probably isn't a good idea.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I don't usually delete and undelete like that. Sometimes I will delete, edit and undelete, but not like I did with that answer. The language used is unfortunate as the question reads like a malignant indictment and makes exaggerated claims.

Comment: Power to you @YvetteColomb I don't know how you deal with this level of scrutiny. Having to answer to folks for such trivial actions seems to be quite a burden. Programmers can be an obsessive lot, and it is tough if you have to answer to us. I hope that you have some healthy ways of dealing with the stress that this kind of attack no doubt brings. Is there a button somewhere that orders a bottle of wine for a moderator? That's healthy stress management, right? Good luck...

Answer (score 5):

Yes, repetitively deleting and undeleting can be frustrating (mod or no mod), and mods should lead by example, but I don't think this behaviour should be addressed in the way it has been.

There certainly are valid reasons to delete and then undelete your answer, in my opinion, especially when your answer has been met with negativity. I think it's a valid step in between to improve your answer.

The workflow I imagine in these situation is something like this:

Post a well-intended and well thought-out answer on meta -> get downvotes and negative comments -> see the answer isn't interpreted as you intended it -> delete it -> revise it -> undelete it.

This is a good thing, in my opinion. If your answer isn't being interpreted as you intend it, or has other serious issues, deleting it temporarily while you revise it is appropriate. This keeps other people from getting the wrong impression, and keeps your answer from accumulating downvotes. For questions on main, I sometimes even advise people to do this, to prevent the question from being closed and downvoted while it's being improved.

Temporarily deleting the post also grants yourself the time to review the edit and think it out before you post it. This keeps people from making the same mistake twice.

You can also temporarily delete your answer if you're not sure you're actually right, and want to verify it and discuss it with peers. Of course, not posting it in the first place if you're not sure is better, but I often think back, and start to doubt, especially after receiving downvotes. After verifying, I can undelete without making any edits.

Of course, I'd rather have everyone word everything perfect in their first attempt, write perfect answers, and generally be perfect. But that's just not a reasonable thing to demand. Even for community-elected moderators.

---

A general piece of advice for people deleting their answers though: **comment first, with your intention**. Then us >10Kers can see why you're doing this. If you're intending to undelete, we might keep the reply we were just writing stored somewhere, while if you keep it deleted, our replies are no longer of use. We can also decide if, when we feel the same, we need to write up our own answer, or not.

<sub>P.S.: I wasn't happy too when I wanted to write a comment about one of these answers, and found out it was deleted. But I think it's a good thing this mod is trying to improve her posts, and be more involved on meta. I think we should be welcoming and understanding towards that.</sub>

Comment: I agree with most of this answer, but there’s one detail: the answer isn’t getting edited between the multiple deletion toggles... For me, that raises an eyebrow.

Comment: Very good advice - comment first. Will do that from this point on.

Comment: @YvetteColomb for my own posts I prefer editing these explaining the reason for deletion (maybe you even can find examples of these in my own post history here at MSO). This way explanation is easier to find for 10kers than if it was in comments and additionally it makes for easier to understand revisions history (comments aren't reflected in it which makes for seemingly cryptic deletion entries)

Comment: @gnat can you give me an example?

Comment: @YvetteColomb it's difficult to me to search for deleted answers here being under 10K. However I could find some examples at other site where rep lets me search with `deleted:1` - since you can't see over there here are pair of screen shots demonstrating how it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZWpq.png (see "deletion explanation" notes at the top of the posts)

Comment: @Cerbrus ^^^ see above - I edit the answers I delete and this indeed makes revisions history easier to understand

Comment: Inconsequential at this point, but just a heads up: "is trying to improve her posts" gives a really big hint to _who_ the mod is (unfortunately), and I don't think that is intended.

Comment: @PasserBy While Cerbrus was trying to keep Yvette "anonymous", I think at least 80% of the readers knew who he was talking about. I'm thinking about opening up a meta post about when to disclose the name, and when not to, because in this case, it was a bit silly to borderline passive agressive to not name her, since everyone knew who he was talking about.

Comment: I was _"borderline passive aggressive"_ by trying not to call out a specific moderator? How does that work?

Comment: @Cerbrus Well, it can feel like discussing something behind someones back. It can be considered rude or passive-agressive to not name someone, and not notify them, while clearly discussing their actions. I think that provoked the tone of the answer by Travis J, in part, and that's why he explicitly did name the person in question. Anyway, disclosure of names on meta is a subject I'd like to address in a separate discussion, since I think it's a difficult subject and done wrong often in both directions (not disclosing a name when you should, and disclosing a name when you shouldn't).

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth: I agree that there's a bit of a dilemma in naming vs anonymous. I figured this would be the safer choice, as naming the moderator could've come across as some kind of grudge / shaming post. Maybe I was wrong, maybe not.