# Can we stop editing deleted posts being bumped to the home page?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, edits, deleted-answers, user-interface

A basic question about the site mechanics. Inspired by some discussion [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/368129/3956566) I decided to edit some deleted posts with an explanation as to why they were deleted, so >10K users could view this, if they stumbled across them.

I did this without realising, editing deleted posts bumps them to the home page (not a discrete way to go about it).

It seems a poor user design to bump deleted posts when they're edited.

Can we stop editing deleted posts being  bumped to the home page?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As [described here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42066/stop-an-edited-deleted-answer-from-bumping-the-question), the intention is to allow mods & 10K users to identify when someone is potentially doing something dodgy.

Remember, undeleting *doesn't* bump - so it'd be pretty easy to hide spam or other forms of abuse by just editing them into a deleted answer, letting it sit for a while, and then undeleting. Making undeletion bump has its own set of potential issues.

If you're making good-faith edits, there's nothing to be worried about; anyone who can see them will recognize what you're doing and move on.

A potentially useful change would be to add some sort of indicator to the question's status or revision history to allow < 10K users to figure out what's happening.

Comment: Dammit shog, I wish I had known this before I edited them all.

Comment: This is how most of us learned... You'll note the MSE Q&A was written with a series of live trials ;-)

Comment: What's the issue regarding bumping undeletion compared to not bumping?

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of bumping a question that has had posts edited on it is to allow people to verify new edits. This is particularly important for old questions, to make sure that someone isn't going around and poking at such things.

If the system doesn't bump due to edits to deleted answers, what then should happen if the answer becomes undeleted? Should that now bump the question? Or should the system check to see if the answer was edited while deleted and only then bump the question?

This seems a fair bit of complexity for things cases that are outliers.